# Mark unused parameters in Kotlin

Tags: suppress-warnings, kotlin, unused-variables

I am defining some functions to be used as callbacks and not all of them use all their parameters.

How can I mark unused parameters so that the compiler won't give me warnings about them?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

With the `@Suppress` annotation You can suppress any diagnostics on any declaration or expression.

Examples:
Suppress warning on parameter:

```
fun foo(a: Int, @Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") b: Int) = a
```

Suppress all UNUSED_PARAMETER warnings inside declaration

```
@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")
fun foo(a: Int,  b: Int) {
  fun bar(c: Int) {}
}

@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")
class Baz {
    fun foo(a: Int,  b: Int) {
        fun bar(c: Int) {}
    }
}
```

Additionally IDEA's intentions(Alt+Enter) can help you to suppress any diagnostics:

[image]

Comment: thanks. is there a way to shorten it to [unused] or something? I tried `annotation class unused : suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")` but it doesn't work due to suppress being final.

Comment: You should be able to omit the brackets, that saves two characters :)

Comment: Additionally You can extract and share annotation parameter.

Comment: My comment applied to the old, now removed annotation syntax and is no longer valid.

Comment: I had listenener methods with multiple arguments and only one was used. I was able to set ```@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")``` above the method. So all three unused arguments of four in total are covered :)

Answer (score 9):

If your parameter is in a lambda, you can use an underscore to omit it.  This removes the unused parameter warnings.  It will also prevent `IllegalArgumentException` in the case that the parameter was null and was marked non-null.

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#underscore-for-unused-variables-since-11

Answer (score 0):

If the functions are part of a class you can declare the containing class `open` or `abstract` and the offending methods as `open`.

```
open class ClassForCallbacks {
  // no warnings here!
  open fun methodToBeOverriden(a: Int, b: Boolean) {}
}
```

Or

```
abstract class ClassForCallbacks {
  // no warnings here!
  open fun methodToBeOverriden(a: Int, b: Boolean) {}
}
```

Answer (score -10):

One can disable these warnings by adding a kotlin compile option flag in build.gradle.
To configure a single task, use its name. Examples:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        suppressWarnings = true
    }
}
```

It is also possible to configure all Kotlin compilation tasks in the project:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If one is using kotlin in Android and want to suppress kotlin compiler warnings, add below in app-module build.gradle file

```
android{
    ....other configurations
    kotlinOptions {
        suppressWarnings = true
    }
}
```

Whether you really need to suppress all kotlin warning for your project or not, its up to you.

Comment: Why would someone suppress the warning for the entire project?? It is not a good practice.

Comment: @"Mahendra Chhimwal" Thank you!  Finally I can disable Jetbrain's annoying style warnings globally.  Now I can code personal projects without Jetbrain's unwanted, unneeded, invasive style warning harassment.  If not for this fix, I'd switch to VSCode.

Comment: @devdanke "Most people don't have that willingness to break bad habits. They have a lot of excuses and they talk like victims." -Carlos Santana     :)