# Unused arguments when destructing an object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

When destructuring an object, is it possible to only declare the variables I need?

In this example I'm only using `b` and my IDE is giving me a warning that `a` is unused.

```
fun run() {
    fun makePair() = Pair("Apple", "Orange")

    val (a, b) = makePair()

    println("b = $b")
}
```

Comment: In other languages, you often have something like `val (_, b) = makePair()`. Nothing similar in Kotlin?

Comment: Somewhat similar question, and somewhat unsatisfactory answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046636/mark-unused-parameters-in-kotlin

Comment: @Thilo Scala has it, but doesn't seem like there is anything like it in Kotlin. At least not yet.

Answer (score 10):

Since Kotlin 1.1, you can use an underscore to mark an unused component of a destructing declaration:

```
fun run() {
    fun makePair() = Pair("Apple", "Orange")

    val (_, b) = makePair()

    println("b = $b")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
val b = makePair().component2()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in the first couple of arguments you can omit the remaining ones. In your code that's not possible, but if you change the order of arguments, you can write it this way:

```
fun run() {
    fun makePair() = Pair("Orange", "Apple")

    val (b) = makePair()

    println("b = $b")
}
```