# Kotlin warnings with gradle build

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

I've been experiencing build performances problems on my Mac since i started converting a project from java to kotlin.

I use gradle with Android Studio 3.0.1

The problem is that when i build/run/compile the source code I get a lot of warnings from the gradle console that are about code naming conventions, let me show you

[image]

I think that this is slowing down my build. I also tried to tweak a little bit my gradle configuration file and build script but nothing happened

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

And also in my build.gradle top

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == "lint" || task.name == "lintVitalRelease") {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

...

```
lintOptions {
    checkAllWarnings false
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    ignoreWarnings true       // false by default
    quiet true                // false by default
    tasks.lint.enabled = false
}
```

And I set the compiler parameters to `-x lint`, so I'm surprised by this error
Anyone has the same problem?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046636/mark-unused-parameters-in-kotlin

Comment: *Parameter "X" is never used. Could be renamed to _* Why don't you follow the prompts and rename those. The warnings will definitely go away.

Comment: As the first warnings indicate, change 'compile' to 'implementation', etc, as that will dramatically improve build performance.

Comment: _Why don't you follow the prompts_ : It's debetable whether or not it's good practice to hide the variable name for unused anonymous functions. I think it's weird that the Kotlin compiler makes that decision for us and make it a warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warnings that you see are reported by the Kotlin compiler, not by Android Lint, so `lintOptions` won't affect them.

Instead, if you want to suppress the warnings, you can configure a single Kotlin compilation task to suppress its warnings:

```
compileDebugKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true
}
```

Or suppress the warnings from all Kotlin compilation tasks:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true
}
```

Though in fact, these warnings should not affect the build performance in any noticeable way.

Comment: Is there any way to solve this without suppressing them?

Comment: Yes, it does not directly affect build performance but when warnings are in 3 or 4 digits it shows down the system while printing them. So indirectly it affects the build system. But if u have that many warnings please try to solve them. But In that case suppressing warning will help build performance and reading app build trace

Comment: even though I suppressed the warnings from all compilation tasks they are still shown! any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of KGP, you can use:

```
android {
    // ...

   kotlinOptions {
       suppressWarnings = true
   }

  // ..
}
```