# How do I suppress Kotlin warnings from Gradle output using command line or local.properties configuration?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I want to suppress Kotlin compiler warnings using either

- Command line switches as input to a single Gradle command
- Device configuration in the file `gradle.properties` or `local.properties`

I do *not* want to check in changed to `build.gradle` permanently disabling warnings. I know this is possible with `kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true` (see i.e. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330264/kotlin-warnings-with-gradle-build)).

The reason is that I want it to be suppressed only when building from a CI server, where warnings are not relevant to our development process and only causing noise. However when building from a local computer I want me and my peers to see the warnings so that we can act on them.

Comment: Just set `kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = isCI` in your `build.gradle` file (and pass this property only on CI server via command line/configuration file - see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html)

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks