# How can I assign a null lambda (String) -> Unit to a variable directly?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I'm studying Code A. I hope to directly assisn a null lambda expression to `onValueChange` for test.

But Code B, Code C and Code D are all wrong, how can I assign a null `lambda (String) -> Unit` to the variable `onValueChange` ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun HelloContent(name2: String, onNameChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        ...
        OutlinedTextField(
            ...
            onValueChange = onNameChange          
        )
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun HelloContent(name2: String, onNameChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        ...
        OutlinedTextField(
            ...
            onValueChange = { }
        )
    }
}
```

**Code C**

```
@Composable
fun HelloContent(name2: String, onNameChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        ...
        OutlinedTextField(
            ...
            onValueChange = null           
        )
    }
}
```

**Code D**

```
@Composable
fun HelloContent(name2: String, onNameChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        ...
        OutlinedTextField(
            ...
            onValueChange = fun(x:String):Unit{ }           
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with B and D?

Comment: Compile error: Parameter 'onNameChange' is never used

Comment: But that's not a problem with what you pass to `onValueChange`; just remove the `onNameChange` parameter, use it somewhere, or suppress the diagnostic as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046636/mark-unused-parameters-in-kotlin).

Comment: Also, for future reference, please always include compile errors, exception stack traces or so on in the question. From the snippets you give it's impossible to tell `onNameChange` isn't used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say where `OutlinedTextField` comes from, but I'm guessing [this one](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#OutlinedTextField(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material.TextFieldColors)). In which case the answer is that you can't; the type is `(String) -> Unit` which is not nullable. And yes, I see parameters like `label: () -> Unit = null`, but this doesn't make sense; not only is `null` not a valid parameter, but how would a `() -> Unit` be interpreted as a label?

But a do-nothing lambda is as in your B and D.