# No "Suppress" hint for "UNUSED_PARAMETER" in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

When I press `Alt+Enter` to show Android Studio's suggestion for unused parameter, I get the pop-up menu below,
[image]

You can see there is no any hint for adding the `@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")`, [however the user has.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29046925/1613961)

My environment is

- Macbook air M1
- Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2
- Kotlin plugin version: 203-1.5.31-release-550-AS7717.8

Comment: Same here. But running on Windows.